# How do I pass an array of Pointers to a structure and allocate the members

Tags: c

ok, heres my code.  I'm trying to pass an array of pointers to a structure to a function.
I need to dynamically allocate each structure and put a pointer to that structure in the array.
When I malloc the second time thru it gets a heap error.
HELP

```
#define MAXSTRUCTS 50
#define MAXBUFF 100


typedef struct {  
 char fullName[41];  
 char address[41];  
 char cityState[41];  
 char zipcode[11];  
} Persons;  

int readData(Persons *structPtrs[]);

int main(void) {

     int totalStructs;  
     Persons *structPtrs[MAXSTRUCTS];  
     totalStructs = 0;  
     structPtrs[0] = NULL;  
     totalStructs = readData(structPtrs);  
}

int readData(Persons *strptr[]) {

    int tStructs = 0;  
    int recs;  
    char inRecord[MAXBUFF];  
    Persons *tmpPtr;  
    tStructs = 0;  
    for (recs=0; recs < MAXSTRUCTS; recs++) {  
        if (gets(inRecord) != NULL) {  
           strptr[recs] = (Persons *)malloc( sizeof(Persons));  
           tmpPtr = strptr[recs];  
           strncpy(tmpPtr->fullName,inRecord,MAXBUFF);  
           gets(inRecord);  
           strncpy(tmpPtr->address,inRecord,MAXBUFF);  
           gets(inRecord);  
           strncpy(tmpPtr->cityState,inRecord,MAXBUFF);  
           gets(inRecord);  
           strncpy(tmpPtr->zipcode,inRecord,MAXBUFF);  
           strptr[recs] = tmpPtr;  
           tStructs++;  
        }  
        else {  
             if ( recs = 0 ) {  
                exit (0);  
             }  
             recs=MAXSTRUCTS;  
        }  
    }  
    return(tStructs);  
}
```

Comment: What heap error? What input do you give it?

Comment: **Never** use `gets`. *Never*.

Comment: heap overflow.  it's not allocating a new structure. It trys to alloc over the old structure.  I can't free it because I need that location

Comment: gets or fgets is not the problem, both work fine.  I've tried it with both and both are legal.  using fgets(inRecords,MAXBUFF,stdin); does not effect what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How do you know your strptr[] has `MAXSTRUCTS` elements?

Comment: The problem is `C`.  It must die, or we will keep seeing this kind of code until the end of mankind.

Comment: I've tried it by populating the data fields with test data and the same problem, so gets is not causing the overflow

Comment: strptr[] is initialized with MAXSTRUCTS ptrs.

Comment: while I prefer c++, unfortunately I'm taking c, and I need to get this to work.

Comment: @reinierpost: Sometimes when the only tool you have is a hammer, you tend to see all problems as nails. Long live C.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything right in regard of passing an array of pointers and allocating memory. What leading to a heap corruption is incorrect usage of `strncpy` function. The arrays where you are trying to copy data to are slightly smaller than `MAXBUFF` in all cases. To fix this, you have to specify the size of destination array instead of `MAXBUFF`. For example, instead of:

```
strncpy(tmpPtr->fullName,inRecord,MAXBUFF);
```

... do (assuming that buffer is already filled with `\0` symbols):

```
strncpy(tmpPtr->fullName,inRecord, sizeof(tmpPtr->fullName) - 1);
```

Also, using `gets` function is not recommended as well as it could easily lead to buffer overruns. Try using `fgets` instead.

Here is your modified example that works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSTRUCTS 2
#define MAXBUFF 100

typedef struct {
  char fullName[41];
  char address[41];
  char cityState[41];
  char zipcode[11];
} Persons;

int readData(Persons *structPtrs[]);

int main ()
{
  int totalStructs;
  int recs;
  Persons *structPtrs[MAXSTRUCTS];
  totalStructs = 0;
  structPtrs[0] = NULL;
  totalStructs = readData(structPtrs);
  for(recs = 0; recs < totalStructs; ++recs) {
    printf ("Record #%d - %s\n", recs + 1, structPtrs[recs]->fullName);
  }
  return 0;
}

int readData(Persons *strptr[])
{
  int tStructs = 0;
  int recs;
  char inRecord[MAXBUFF];
  Persons *tmpPtr;
  tStructs = 0;
  for (recs=0; recs < MAXSTRUCTS; ++recs) {
    memset (inRecord, 0, sizeof(inRecord));
    if (fgets(inRecord, sizeof (inRecord) - 1, stdin))
      {
      strptr[recs] = (Persons *)malloc(sizeof(Persons));
      tmpPtr = strptr[recs];
      memset (tmpPtr, 0, sizeof(Persons));
      strncpy(tmpPtr->fullName,inRecord,sizeof(tmpPtr->fullName) - 1);
      fgets(inRecord, sizeof (inRecord) - 1, stdin);
      strncpy(tmpPtr->address,inRecord,sizeof(tmpPtr->address) - 1);
      fgets(inRecord, sizeof (inRecord) - 1, stdin);
      strncpy(tmpPtr->cityState,inRecord, sizeof(tmpPtr->cityState) - 1);
      fgets(inRecord, sizeof (inRecord) - 1, stdin);
      strncpy(tmpPtr->zipcode,inRecord, sizeof (tmpPtr->zipcode) - 1);
      strptr[recs] = tmpPtr;
      tStructs++;
    } else {
      if ( recs = 0 ) {
    exit (0);
      }
      recs=MAXSTRUCTS;
    }
  }
  return(tStructs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I'll give that a try.  I can see where strncpy can cause a problem, but I would think it would fail on the first time.  unfortunately can't use memset, forced to use malloc.

Comment: @George: `memset` and `malloc` are totally different things. `memset`  fills already allocated memory with the constant byte specified as a second argument. You may not use it, but then you will have to take care of putting '\0' where it is needed manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int readDataToRecord( Persons *eachEntry[] ) {
```

```
int numEntries = 0 ;

Persons *tempPtr ;

for( int i=0 ; i < NUM_OF_RECORDS; ++i ) {

    eachEntry[i] = ( Record * ) malloc( sizeof( Record ) ) ;
    memset( eachEntry[i], 0, sizeof( Record ) ) ;

    tempPtr = eachEntry[i] ;

    fgets( tempPtr->firstName,  sizeof( tempPtr->firstName ), stdin ) ;
    fgets( tempPtr->secondName, sizeof( tempPtr->secondName), stdin ) ;

    eachEntry[i] = tempPtr ;

    ++numEntries ;
}

return numEntries ;
```

}

This would also efficiently do the job. Once you have new record, you would any how have the memory allocated for each of its member. So you can directly fgets to that variable.

@Vlad : Please let me know if I am wrong.